# How to turn Linksys-WRT54GL v1.1 to monitor mode?

Tags: wireless-networking, openwrt, sniffing, network-monitoring

First I am using Linksys-WRT54GL v1.1 and OpenWRT using b43 driver.
I tried many times to capture packets in monitoring mode 
and I did the following step

create interface

```
 
iw phy phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor
ifconfig mon0 up
```

Then I am using  tcpdump 
when I want to use  I got the error
when I use (-i ) it  enters the promiscuous mode as the kernel log file indicates.

```
tcpdump: eth0: That device doesn't support monitor mode
```

as the error message inform that Linksys-WRT54GL v1.1 doesn't support monitor mode

Can any one give any way to turn the monitoring mode on  doesn't support monitor mode from OpenWRT.

The second problem:
I am not able to install the aircrack-ng because there is no memory space on the router. If there is any light version.

Thank you in advanced